# Retrieving elements from a data.frame when the addressed column is misspelled

Tags: r, dataframe

I stumbled on some strange behavior of R when working with a data.frame called `DS.inp`.

In this data.frame I have a column called `"DATE_EGFR_CREAT"`. When I wanted to print the elements of this column in the console to see what data this column contained, I accidentally used a misspelled version of this column name:   `"DS.inp$DATE_EGFR"`.  Still, R provided the results from `"DATE_EGFR_CREAT"` in the console. This was rather unexpected, as there is no column called `"DATE_EGFR"` in the data.frame `DS.inp`.

The following code was used to verify whether the misspelled column was in my data.frame originally:

```
> "DATE_EGFR" %in% names(DS.inp)
FALSE
```

Knowing what is causing this behavior in R might have a lot of impact on my work.

Does someone know what is going on here?

Comment: Need a repreducable reproducible example for this. R does have a tab auto complete which may have corrected without you noticing?

Comment: The `$` accessor function uses partial matching so incomplete variable names can still be matched so long as they uniquely identify a match - see for example `mtcars$m` returns `mtcars$mpg` but `mtcars$c` returns `NULL` as it could match either `cyl` and `carb`.  This is documented in `help("Extract")`.